# VB.NET Search string

Tags: vb.net, string

I want to search a specific part of a string in VB.NET. For example in the string below I want the following part: "Tennis".

```
Football ... Basketball ... Tennis ... Golf
```

I'm not sure how I would crop out the other part of the string so that im left with Tennis. Thanks :)

Comment: What is the criteria?  Position?  Word Count? Text?  *Searching* - as per the title - is easy: `Dim HasTennis = sportsText.Contains("Tennis")`

Comment: From the string above I want to crop out everything other than "Tennis". How would I do this ?

Comment: I don't want to use Contains because I need to find the index. It's not always going to be Tennis on the third position.

Comment: Is it always going to be the third word you want? `It's not always going to be `, but above you want ?

Comment: yes always that third position but the third word may change ie. to soccer

Comment: Ok thanks for confirmation. What framework you using?

Comment: net framework 4.5 , thanks :)

Comment: Use Split() to break the string up based on the "..." characters into an array. Then take the 3rd element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below is my thought... You can use this function in any class you want, you pass it the string you want to check, what we should split on and finally what position do we want to get... I hope you do not mind Linq and lamda expression's...

```
 ''' <summary>
''' Return's word at index if it exist.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Sentence"></param>
''' <param name="SplitString"></param>
''' <param name="Position"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Shared Function GetWordAtPosition(ByVal Sentence As String, ByVal SplitString As String, ByVal Position As Integer) As String
    Dim ReturnWord As String = String.Empty
    Dim ListPossibleWords As New List(Of String)

    Try
        'First see if we have a string, it's not empty or null, we have something to split on, and the actual word
        'at the given position...
        If Sentence IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Sentence) AndAlso SplitString IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(SplitString) AndAlso Position > -1 Then
            'Trim the string out...
            Sentence = Sentence.Trim.Replace(" ", String.Empty)

            'Does the string have what we need to split on?
            If Sentence.Contains(SplitString) Then
                'Split all this into a List(Of String)...
                With ListPossibleWords
                    .AddRange(Strings.Split(Sentence, SplitString.ToCharArray))
                    .RemoveAll(Function(s As String) As Boolean
                                   Return s.Equals(SplitString)
                               End Function)
                End With

                'Do we have a list now?
                If ListPossibleWords.Count >= Position Then ReturnWord = ListPossibleWords.Item(Position - 1)

            End If

        End If

        Return ReturnWord
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ReturnWord
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Nice answer. Not to be rude, but wouldn't a Regex be simpler?

Comment: @VisualVincent I totally agree `Regex` would be simpler, but then again there are more than a few way's to do this, right :) I just wrote up a quick example to do what he needed to do, although it can be modified relatively easy if need to be. I did start at first with all `Linq`, but grew a little long and didn't want to confuse the OP if he doesn't know `Linq`...

Answer (score 0):

The following might do what you want.

```
Module VBModule

    Sub Main()
        Dim sSearchIn As String = "Football ... Basketball ... Tennis ... Golf"
        Dim sSearchFor As String = " ... " 
        Dim lItemPosition As Long = 3
        Dim lSkipLen As Long = sSearchFor.Length

        Dim lIndex As Long
        Dim sTemp as String

        Dim i As Long



        ' Mid is one-based, IndexOf is zero-based
        sTemp = sSearchIn
        For lIndex = 1 To lItemPosition - 1
            sTemp = Mid (sTemp, sTemp.IndexOf(sSearchFor) + 1 + lSkipLen)
        Next lIndex

        i = sTemp.IndexOf(sSearchFor)

        If (i > 0) Then
            Console.WriteLine(Left (sTemp, i))
        Else
            Console.WriteLine(sTemp)
        End If
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: `Mid`, `Left` and such are highly outdated. They only exist for backwards compability. I recommend you to start using the newer methods instead.